# How in vuex.js to save in the "store" the text entered in the input? Where did i make a mistake?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I suffer the third day. Help me please. How in vuex.js save the text entered into the input in the "store", and then add it to the Value of the same input itself.

I'm trying to do it like this but somewhere I make a mistake.

HTML

```
<f7-list-input
  label="Username"
  name="username"
  placeholder="Username"
  type="text"
  :value="newUserName"
  @input="username = $event.target.value"
  required validate
  pattern="[3-9a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]+"
  v-model="saveUserName"
/>
```

SCRIPT

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      username: '',
      password: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    signIn() {
      const self = this;
      const app = self.$f7;
      const router = self.$f7router;
      router.back();
      app.dialog.alert(`Username: ${self.username}<br>Password: ${self.password}`, () => {
        router.back();
      });
    },
    saveUserName(){
        this.$store.commit(saveName);
    }
  },
  computed:{
     userName(){
         return this.$store.state.newUserName;
     }
  }
};
```

STORE

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state:{
        userNameStor: 'newUserName',
        userPasswordStor:''
    },
    mutations:{
        saveName(state){
            userNameStor:newUserName;
            return newUserName;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's explain the whole functionnality, and then some code.

The input is in the template part of a component.

The component contain also a script part, which trigger code based on template events and so on.
The component code can trigger mutations (for state change), which are the way you store something in the store.

you have this screen to store flow:

1/ component template event => 2/ component script code => 3/ execute mutation on store

For the other side, you have this:
state => mapMutation in component computed property => component template.

Inside component script you can map a store value into a computed property of the component (with mapMutations helper). Then you map this field in your template from the component computed property.

1 - Your template
@input is the event occuring when input change by user action.
:value is the value of the input, defined programmatically.
v-model is a shorcut for using @input and :value at the same time. Don't use it with :value and @input.

Ok minimal Template:

```
<f7-list-input
  type="text"
  :value="username"
  @input="changeUsername"
/>
```

Inside the script, you just have to link the changeUsername method to the mutation (with mapMutation), and also define a computed property whose name is username and that is a map of username from the store (with mapState).

```
import {mapState, mapMutations} from "vuex"

   export default {
      methods:{
         ...mapMutations({
        changeUsername:"saveName"
      },
      computed:{
         ...mapState({
            username:state=>state.username
        }),
      }
    };
```

Consider looking at Vue doc about this [mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html) and [state](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html)

Comment: I forgot to say that the input is not the main vue.js, it is a separate component login.js

Comment: Not a problem, it work the same. mapState, mapMutations and mapActions works in every component.

Comment: You're welcomed. Vue is awesome after some work on it.
Just vote for the answer as this is my feedback :)

Comment: Can you please help me with this? I can’t figure out how to transfer a value from input to a block before saving it in localstorage. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55799648/why-the-value-from-input-is-not-passed-to-vuex