# Why the value from input is not passed to VUEX

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, html-framework-7

I can't transfer the **value** from **input** to the **store**. When I click on the **add item** button, I need to create a **block** with its **delete button** and the text entered in the **input**. And then save it all in localstorage. But now I am creating only a new **block** without text. Please help me fix my code to make it work.

**Here's how it should work**

[image]

**But how it works now**

[image]

What I'm doing wrong? How do I transfer the value from Input to Vuex?

**Here is my code**

```html
<template>

      <f7-block-title>Some items</f7-block-title>
      <f7-block v-for="(cat, n) in getCats" :key="n">
        <span>{{ cat }}</span>
        <f7-button fill color="red" @click="removeCat(n)">Delete Cat</f7-button>
      </f7-block>
      <f7-list form>
        <f7-list-input :value="tempCat" type="text"></f7-list-input>
        <f7-button fill color="blue" @click="addCat(tempCat)">Add some item</f7-button>
      </f7-list>

</template>

    <script>
    import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';
    export default {
      data () {
        return {
          tempCat: '',
        };
      },
      computed:{
        ...mapGetters([
          'getCats',
        ]),
      },
      methods: {
        ...mapActions([
          'addCat',
          'removeCat',
        ])
      }
    }
    </script>
```

**Code in VUEX**

```
function loadLocalStorage() {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cats'));
  } catch(e) {
    localStorage.removeItem('cats');
    return [];
  }
}

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      cats: loadLocalStorage(),
    },
    getters:{
      getCats: state => state.cats,
    },
    actions: {
      addCat(context, data) {
        context.commit('ADD_CAT', data);
        context.commit('SAVE_CATS');
      },
      removeCat(context, data) {
        context.commit('REMOVE_CAT', data);
        context.commit('SAVE_CATS');
      },
    },

    mutations: {
    ADD_CAT(state, data) {
        state.cats.push(data);
        console.log(state.cats);
    },
    SAVE_CATS(state) {
      localStorage.setItem('cats', JSON.stringify(state.cats));
      console.log(state.cats);
    },
    REMOVE_CAT(state, index) {
      state.cats.splice(index, 1);
    },
},
});
```

GitHub link https://github.com/MrRJDio/ex1

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code doesn't respect the VueX state management standard. [This article](https://medium.com/vue-mastery/vuex-explained-visually-f17c8c76d6c4) explains very well how to make proper use of VueX.

Some valid Vuex would like this:

**Vue file:**

```html
<template>
  <f7-block strong>
    <f7-block-title>Some items</f7-block-title>
    <f7-block v-for="(cat, n) in getCats" :key="n">
      <span>{{ cat }}</span>
      <f7-button fill color="red" @click="removeCat(n)">Delete Cat</f7-button>
    </f7-block>
    <f7-list form>
      <f7-list-input :value="tempCat" type="text" placeholder="Заметка"></f7-list-input>
      <f7-button fill color="blue" @click="addCat(tempCat)">Add some item</f7-button>
    </f7-list>
  </f7-block>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      tempCat: '',
    };
  },
  computed:{
    ...mapGetters([
      'getCats',
    ]),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([
      'addCat',
      'removeCat',
    ])
  }
}
</script>
```

**Store:**

```js
function loadLocalStorage() {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cats'));
  } catch(e) {
    localStorage.removeItem('cats');
    return [];
  }
}

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    cats: loadLocalStorage(),
  },
  getters:{
    getCats: state => state.cats,
  },
  actions: {
    addCat(context, data) {
      context.commit('ADD_CAT', data);
      context.commit('SAVE_CATS');
    },
    removeCat(context, data) {
      context.commit('REMOVE_CAT', data);
      context.commit('SAVE_CATS');
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_CAT(state, data) {
      state.cats.push(data);
    },
    SAVE_CATS(state) {
      localStorage.setItem('cats', JSON.stringify(state.cats));
    },
    REMOVE_CAT(state, index) {
      state.cats.splice(index, 1);
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: When I click the add button, I get an error  `"unknown action type: addCat"`

Comment: See my latest edit. Action name was miswritten, but you could have found out by yourself.

Comment: Did not notice. Fix it.  Now when I try to add something, I get an Error in v-on handler: `"TypeError: state.getters is undefined"`. Blocks are added but without text from the input.

Comment: Indeed, I thought I was in the context, sorry. Try `state.cats` instead of `state.getters.getCats`

Comment: You have to provide debug statements, instead of asking us to code for you. Do you use Vue DevTools to check the state of your store ? Do you console.log to check if the cat is added ?

Comment: I usually do like you say and in general I try not to ask for help, but Vue is somehow hard for me.  I hope I understood everything correctly. Vue Devtools Vuex https://ibb.co/4PtmQWM    Vue Devtools Events  https://ibb.co/F8MQpBd     console.log(state.cats); in SAVE_CATS   https://ibb.co/0YrRBVm

Comment: Look at your console logs. You have in your array an empty string. By the way, I removed the `@change` event because you don't have to keep looking for changes. The `v-model` is here to keep track of what you are typing. `v-model` binds the text input to your value in your datas, and also puts the data in the text field. This is two way-binding. Check this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Comment: Unfortunately, v-model is not supported in framework7.

Comment: You have have told us. Check this solution https://github.com/framework7io/framework7-vue/issues/356#issuecomment-365363205